# How to install from a Git repo

Tags: kali-linux, github

I just cloned this repo. I do not know how to install it. I cd-ed to it and typed `$ sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms` but it didn't seem to work out. The repo is:
https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

Comment: If you are new to Linux, please reconsider your desire to use Kali. It is intended for advanced users.

Comment: Are you sure Kali is the right Linux distribution to learn the fundamentals of using Linux with? Maybe their website can help you answering this question: https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux.

Answer (score 2):

The installation instructions on the repository site are:

> 1. Install DKMS and other required tools

```
$ sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms
```

> 2. Add the driver to DKMS. This will copy the source to a system directory so that it can used to rebuild the module on kernel upgrades.

```
$ sudo dkms add .
```

> 3. Build and install the driver.

```
$ sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
```

You said you've only executed the first step, which only prepares the tools needed to compile and install the driver. All three steps are needed.

The second command should be run in the top directory of your cloned repository; the first and the last command can be run anywhere.